# CF Client Variables: is the CDATA - CGLOBAL relationship always 1:1?

Tags: sql-server, session, coldfusion

We've noticed something odd with our Coldfusion 8 client variables DB. We have many more (about 3 times as many) CGlobal entries as we have CData entries.

I would have assumed that the relationship would be 1:1 on the `cfid` column.

Has any one else noticed this before? I have ruled out old data, my sample is less than 3 hours old. We're using SQL Server 2000 to host the tables.

Thanks in advance,
Ciaran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that an application that uses client variables will always have a `cGlobal` record for a client but will only have a `cData` record for a client if the client scope is actually written to, e.g. `<cfset client.foo = "bar" />`.

So this is reasonable behaviour but it seemed odd to me because I thought we always wrote to the client scope for every request.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly are you worried about this? Is there some other suspicious behavior, or a bug that you're trying to track down? Are your client variables not working as expected?

ColdFusion's client variables were implemented a long time ago and I don't think it would be done the same way today if they had it to do over again (for starters, the db tables could use an overhaul). But just because there isn't a 1:1 relationship between the tables doesn't necessarily mean there's something wrong.

Comment: just trying to understand why it's doing this, that's all. It's not actually causing any immediate problem.